# How to return an undone commit in GitHub

Tags: git, undo, github-for-windows

I have done my project and wanted to commit it using GitHub Desktop.

While it was committing my first commit I understood that I don't want one folder to be in that commit, so I clicked the Revert button. Then I found my project repository empty! I tried to return my files clicking the "Undo most recent commit" button.

So now I haven't got neither files nor commits (I didn't published anything).

Git log and git reflog show that I don't have any commits.

How can I get my project back?

I am sorry for an unclear explanation as I've just started to use Git.

Comment: it shows that current branch master does not have any commits yet

Comment: @AD7six, I am using Windows. And I was doing everything 
instinctively. Before it worked =(

Answer (score 3):

run `git reflogs`: it will show you the sha1 of the last commits you were on. Then you just need to checkout the commit you're interested in, and to put a branch on it.

For instance, say the first lines of this command are:

```
c5e511a HEAD@{0}: checkout: moving from e9c02de51d808c91ac2abbac39166b1daf150452 to origin/master
e9c02de HEAD@{1}: checkout: moving from c5e511a7b64da6f52c514f770959e48c3b503169 to e9c02
c5e511a HEAD@{2}: commit: final commit of my project
```

and say you recognize that the last line represent the commit you're interested in. Then you can just run:

```
git checkout c5e511a
git checkout -B master
```

and voilà: your `master` branch is back right were it belongs.

Note that you may also find useful the command

```
git show <sha1>
```

since it will give more info about a particular commit

---

On the other hand, if you delete a change that hasn't been commited, then it is lost.
In that case, rest assure that I know what your pain feels like... and the good news is that you'll never make this error again!

Comment: git reflog says that I don't have any commits

Comment: You can also specify reflog entries as HEAD@{n} as show in the reflog.

Answer (score 0):

you reverted everything and since nothing was committed before all is gone id guess

Comment: There needs to be a commit for revert to work (and the end result would be _two_ commits). The op may be confused by terminology but this seems unlikely to answer (or help) anything.

Comment: He discarded uncommitted stuff imo and I agree partly that this doesn't help but it is also an answer. Given the reflog is empty the only one I see

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have lost all your work :-( and that you will learn the first and most important rule of git:

"first, commit whenever you can to save your work and after do whatever you want (amend, rebase, merge, reset,...) you will always be able to undo and retry what you want to do!"

The second rule is take 5 min to understand the `reflog` command to be able to find some "lost" commits to easily undo some actions done following the first rule.

That's nearly all you need to never lost ever again some work with git...

Answer (score 0):

## Moaning

I'm really not a fan of these answers that say:"I don't know how to fix it so you've obviously lost everything, be more careful in future"

Just because you don't know how to do something doesn't mean you should say it's impossible! It's actually kind of unhelpful because if things are possible and you just don't know then you are spreading lies :P.

## Possible approaches

Anyway, cases like this are likely to idiomatic so there probably isn't a single command that will consistently work. But you could try some of the following:

### Backup

**Before you do anything** create a backup of the repo directory with `cp -r`

### Overview of how git works

Now, git should not through away any of commits until it garbage collects: something that I believe has to be done manually. This means, hopefully, your commits are present. It's just you don't the reference of your old `master`.

You might want to review https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Git-Objects to understand the git object model. A "tl;dr" is that a git repository is a big tree with pointers. These pointers are sha references.

### You might be lucky

The `git reflog` file works by looking in `.git/logs`, in my case I had somehow managed to delete the file `.git/logs/refs/heads/master` file. However the file `.git/logs/head` still existed, so I could find a reference to my previous branch.

Allowing me to run `git reset --hard COMMIT_FOUND_IN_FILE`

The plumbing command `git show-ref` also referred the sha of my old branch.

### Or you might need to work hard

Even in the absence of these clues, it is technically possible to find leaves of git's dag, one of these leaves will then be your old branch.

The command `git rev-list --objects --all` shows every object in your free, and `git cat-file` can examine these objects.

`git rev-list --objects --all --graph` will attempt to draw something vaguely graph like with your commits. I wasn't quite sure what the output was but the first result was my master.